# How may I scrape the price under the li

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here are my codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Gaming-Video-Cards/PromotionStore/ID-1197? 
cm_sp=Cat_Video-Cards_1-_-TopNav-_-Gaming-Video-Cards'
my_url

gamestore = ureq(my_url)
page_html = gamestore.read()
gamestore.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})
```

The problem came with these two lines below:

```
pricetag = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"})
pricetag
```

The results are:
[image]
All I want is to get the price, which is

```
</span>$<strong>599</strong><sup>.99</sup>
```

How may I do it?

Comment: You can look further for `<strong>` and `<sup>` tags inside that output and combine them into price, can't you?

Answer (score 1):

To get the price you might use a [css selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)`div.item-container li.price-current strong` to get the strong elements and use `findNextSibling` to get the `sup` element.

```
containers = page_soup.select("div.item-container li.price-current strong")

for c in containers:
    print(c.text +  c.findNextSibling('sup').text)
```

That will result in:

```
599.99
369.99
..
```